# How to restrict access to file based on metadata?

Tags: permissions, security, access, item-level-permissions

I'm looking for a way to restrict access to certain types of records based on their metadata. Basically there are some types of files that all employees in a team should see, and some they shouldn't (ie in terms of HR records, anyone in HR should see basic records, yet only the managers and investigation team should see complaint records).

I've had a look into sensitivity labels and this doesn't seem to be the right fit (although I could be wrong!). Is there another way to do this? How would you restrict access to a single 'type' of file in sharepoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support permissions management based on metadata. The best practice it to store sensitive documents separately, in a different SharePoint library or at least a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Drop Off Libraries can help you a lot.

Seperate your HR Folders with required permissions and redirect your files into these folders with rules.

Take a look at here - [Create Content Organizer rules to route documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-content-organizer-rules-to-route-documents-1e4d37a3-635d-4764-b0fc-f7c5356c1900)